# How to sort numeric with string values in Kendo-Grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using Kendo-Grid which is having a column has values of both number & string (NA). Any idea how to sort them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its working with the code avilable in http://jsbin.com/egoneWe/3/edit

Comment: Just replace the zeros with whatever string you like using the template function. Thank you JPN, this was a very helpful post for me.

Comment: here's an updated jsbin with secure links to the libraries. http://jsbin.com/sezipoqebu/1/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 8):

You can sort them using a custom compare function. Here is some sample code which will put items with **'N/A'** on top:

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  dataSource: [
    { price: 1 },
    { price: "N/A" },
    { price: 20 },
    { price: 2 }
  ],
  sortable: true,
  columns: [
    {
      field: "price",
      sortable: {
        compare: function(a, b) {
          var x = a.price;
          var y = b.price;

          if (x == 'N/A') {
            x = 0;
          }

          if (y == 'N/A') {
            y = 0;
          }

          return x - y;
        }
      }
    }
  ]
});
```

Here is a live demo: http://jsbin.com/urUXOCa/1/edit

Comment: This demo works well and I have edited it and added few more values and it works perfect. But the same logic is not working for me. I think the reason could be that I am not using jQuery and I am unsing Angular-Kendo. Any idea how to make this sortable: {compare:....}} working with angular-kendo

Comment: In the example, how do we get the column a.price dynamically. Atleast how to fetch the value field into var x = a.$field (something like that). Is that possible

Comment: http://jsbin.com/yitugitece/edit?html,js,output a version of this answer working with secure css and jquery referneces

Answer (score 0):

Make the field values as numbers. Then, if required, add the string at the time of displaying.

Kindly refer this for help :[sorting numbers (dollar amt and percentage) not working](http://www.kendoui.com/forums/kendo-ui-web/grid/sorting-numbers-dollar-amt-and-percentage-not-working.aspx)

Comment: aaron - How can I add the string at the time of display? Can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there isn't a way to create your own sort function your for a field.
I did find http://sympletech.com/how-to-enable-case-insensitive-sorting-on-kendo-ui-grid/ where someone implemented something like what you are asking (he was just doing case in-sensitive sorting).

I've had to do this once (thankfully on a non-editable grid, was just showing data), and I just sort of tricked the grid using a template. By going through the data before it was dataBound, adding another property to it that represented the data that would sort properly, and binding the grid to that column instead of the original column, but using a template that returned the original data value.

See jsbin http://jsbin.com/ETaZOSu/1/edit

Comment: From your jsbin, I couldn't understand from where you are calling valueTemplate(e)

Comment: In the columns collection on the grid.    columns: [
    { field: "name", title: "Name" },
    { field: "sort", title: "Value", template: valueTemplate }
  ]